# Tables Stretching divs

Tags: html, css, gwt

I'm using a div based layout and GWT which LOVES to use tables everywhere. The problem I'm encountering is that the tables can stretch beyond the height of the div they are contained in.  Is there anyway to expand the div vertically if needed?

BTW content is being added to the table using javascript if that matters.

If you want to check out what I'm playing with go [here](http://kevmoapp.appspot.com/).  Just add a whold bunch of text to the input box and you will see.

Comment: You need to give more details about the CSS/markup being used.  DIVs will by default stretch to fit their contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of height:100%; in .main-area. If you have to, use min-height.

Comment: Thanks.  The only problem with min-height is IE... god I hate IE

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of tables, build layout with [HTMLPanel](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.6/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/HTMLPanel.html) widget and fill it with interactive elements (other widgets).